# MessageDialog not closing

Tags: mono, dialog, gtk#

I'm using the following code to show a message dialog in my application :

```
MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(null,
                                         DialogFlags.Modal,
                                         MessageType.Error, 
                                         ButtonsType.Ok,
                                         "An error occured: " );
dialog.Run();
```

Problem is the Ok button on the window doesn't do anything.... The window only disappears when i hit the X button on top right corner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `dialog.Destroy();` after your call to `dialog.Run();`

Answer (score 1):

You can also hook the `Response` event to get notified of a button click:

```
    var dialog = new MessageDialog (this,
                                    DialogFlags.Modal, 
                                    MessageType.Info, 
                                    ButtonsType.YesNo, 
                                    "The Hulk could totally take Super Man");
    dialog.Response += (object o, ResponseArgs args) => {
        if (args.ResponseId == ResponseType.Yes) {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes clicked");
        } else if (args.ResponseId == ResponseType.No) {
            Console.WriteLine("No clicked");
        } else if (args.ResponseId == ResponseType.DeleteEvent) {
            Console.WriteLine("Dialog closed without clicking a button");
        }
        dialog.Destroy();
    };

    dialog.Run();
```

Comment: The only solution that works for me. dlg.Destroy() prevents dialog even to appear.